# How can I enable Implicit Grant in WSO2 3.2.0 APIM?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

**Implicit Grant type** was there in WSO2 API manager 3.0.0 like this (in create application flow),
[image] but now it's not available in the 3.2.0 version.
[image] is there a simple way to re-enable it?

**I'm aware of Implicit Grant is Deprecated and has been removed from many applications**. but what I want to do is test old sample application.
Nothing mentioned about this change in their changelog
[v 3.1.0](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.1.0/getting-started/about-this-release/#!),
[v 3.2.0](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/getting-started/about-this-release/#!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the implicit grant type is not displayed in WSO2 APIM-3.2.0 devportal for the applications. You can enable it via the admin portal. Please follow the below steps.

1. Navigate to admin portal via https://{hostname}:{port}/admin
2. On the left menu panel click on "Key Managers"
3. Click on "Resident Key Manager"
4. Under "Grand Types" add **implicit** and press enter
   [image]
5. Click on "Update"
6. Navigate to devportal via https://{hostname}:{port}/devportal
7. Open an application and navigate to "Production Keys"
8. Now you can see the implicit grant type checkbox
   [image]
   The above steps will allow you to have the implicit grant type for all the applications and you don't have to enable the implicit grant type for each and every application you create.

This has been done on purpose as the OAuth 2.1.0 has removed/discouraged the use of the implicit grant type due to security concerns. Please refer [link](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-14#section-2.1.2) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit :** *I posted this before accepting the correct answer & keep it here as a workaround.*

I found a <s>solution</s> workaround, You can still add that grant type by using Management Console (https://localhost:9443/carbon/).

In Management Console,
Service Providers > list > Edit "created application" > Inbound Authentication Configuration > OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration > Edit